# SCNGeometry / SCNCylinder render edges / border only (Store color, clear content)

Tags: ios, opengl-es, render, scenekit, metal

I'm trying to figure out how to have an SCNScylinder on sceen with only a border / stroke / edge visible. Everything in my scene is working fine and i was thinking of just applying a clear color to specular.contents

is the use of a SCNNode delegate / Metal code required (i'm not using opengl on my scene)

Any pointers? help is appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WWDC 2014 presentation showed orbiting cubes that had only wireframes. The technique was to use an image with green edges but transparent interior as the material. From AAPLSlideScenegraphSummary.m:

```
        // A node that will help visualize the position of the stars
        _wireframeBoxNode = [SCNNode node];
        _wireframeBoxNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, M_PI_4);
        _wireframeBoxNode.geometry = [SCNBox boxWithWidth:1 height:1 length:1 chamferRadius:0];
        _wireframeBoxNode.geometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = [NSImage imageNamed:@"box_wireframe"];
        _wireframeBoxNode.geometry.firstMaterial.lightingModelName = SCNLightingModelConstant; // no lighting
        _wireframeBoxNode.geometry.firstMaterial.doubleSided = YES; // double sided
```

[image]

For a similar effect with SCNCylinder, you might need to pass an array of materials, some with border and some without.

**Edit**

For High Sierra/iOS 11 and higher, the answer by @mnuages is a simpler/better approach.

Comment: Thanks Hal, seems to be just what i needed

Answer (score 5):

it requires some effort but you could inspect your cylinder's `geometryElements` and `geometrySources` to build a new `SCNGeometry` with a `primitiveType` of `SCNGeometryPrimitiveTypeLine`

**Edit**

Starting iOS 11 `SCNMaterial` exposes the [`fillMode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterial/2867442-fillmode) property that can be used to render a geometry as a wireframe.

Comment: How do I do it? Searched enough but coudn't get any resource. :(

Comment: You can now use the `fillMode` property of `SCNMaterial` to achieve that easily.

Comment: As I am totally new to this field, can you please help me with a bit of code?

Answer (score 3):

I appreciate that this is an old post, but I recently had to implement something like this an ARKit project.

Firstly I created a square image in Adobe Illustrator which had green edges, but a transparent centre. This is called 'outlinedFace'.

I then created an SCNNode (Swift 4) as follows:

```
import UIKit
import ARKit

class CubeNode: SCNNode {

private var faceArray = [SCNMaterial]()
private let FACE_OUTLINE = "outlinedFace"

/// Initialization With Outline Only
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - width: Optional CGFloat (Defaults To 20cm)
///   - height: Optional CGFloat (Defaults To 20cm)
///   - length: Optional CGFloat (Defaults To 20cm)
///   - colours: [UIColor] - [Front, Right , Back , Left, Top , Bottom]
init(width: CGFloat = 0.2, height: CGFloat = 0.2, length: CGFloat = 0.2) {

    super.init()

    self.geometry = SCNBox(width: width, height: height, length: length, chamferRadius: 0)

        for _ in 0 ..< 6{
            let face = SCNMaterial()
            face.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: FACE_OUTLINE)
            face.isDoubleSided = true
            face.lightingModel = .constant
            faceArray.append(face)
        }

    self.geometry?.materials = faceArray
    self.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, .pi / 4)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

}
```

The key here is making the contents doubled sided.

This works wonderfully for me!